# Php while loop instead foreach to get array data

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

On backend I have rest api, the code is:

```
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
            global $user_id;
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // fetch task
            $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

            $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

        if ($result != NULL) {

            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["id"] = $result["id"];
            $response["task"] = $result["task"];
            $response["status"] = $result["status"];
            $response["createdAt"] = $result["created_at"];
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
            echoRespnse(404, $response);
        }
        });
```

and with this code I get just first data from array:

```
{
error: false
id: 2
task: "Create something"
status: 0
createdAt: "2014-12-01 01:58:42"
}
```

now when I want to fetch all data I write:

```
if ($result != NULL) {
                foreach ($result as $rez) {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["id"] = $rez["id"];
                $response["task"] = $rez["task"];
                $response["status"] = $rez["status"];
                $response["createdAt"] = $rez["created_at"];
                echoRespnse(200, $response);
                }
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
                echoRespnse(404, $response);
            }
```

so the same code with foreach loop but then I get: `Unexpected token {`

What is wrong with that? How I can implement here `WHILE` loop instead `foreach` ???

**UPDATE with function:**

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $res = array();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);
            // TODO
            // $task = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->fetch();
            $res["id"] = $id;
            $res["task"] = $task;
            $res["status"] = $status;
            $res["created_at"] = $created_at;
            $item[] = $res;
            $stmt->close();
            return $item;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get "Unexpected token {"?

Comment: yes, I do this sorry for mistake in cde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the results as an array and send the entire array when the loop ends:

```
if ($result != NULL) {
    $items = array();

    foreach ($result as $rez) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["id"] = $rez["id"];
        $response["task"] = $rez["task"];
        $response["status"] = $rez["status"];
        $response["createdAt"] = $rez["created_at"];

        $items[] = $response;
    }

    echoRespnse(200, $items);
} else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
    echoRespnse(404, $response);
}
```

And `echoRespnse()` should json_encode the $items array.

Also, in your `getAllUserTasks()` function, you should use a while loop to fetch all the results from db:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $items = $res = array();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);

    // fetch values
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $res["id"] = $id;
        $res["task"] = $task;
        $res["status"] = $status;
        $res["created_at"] = $created_at;

        $items[] = $res;
    }

    $stmt->close();

    return $items;
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: ok, but now I get wrong data like this: [4]
0:  {
error: false
id: null
task: null
status: null
createdAt: null
}-
1:  {
error: false
id: "C"
task: "C"
status: "C"
createdAt: "C"
}-
2:  {
error: false
id: null
task: null
status: null
createdAt: null
}-
3:  {
error: false
id: "2"
task: "2"
status: "2"
createdAt: "2"
}

Comment: @LaraBeginer Maybe you implemented my recommendation in the wrong place ? See my updated example.

Comment: again I get just: [1]
0:  {
error: false
id: 2
task: "Create something"
status: 0
createdAt: "2014-12-01 01:58:42"
} so just first data (first user task from tasks) I will update code with funcction getAllUserTasks () now

Comment: Its a good answer but peformance is worst that using get_result() function from my localhost ... but again THANKS!